# accessToken on faceook php sdk 4.0 and Javascript sdk on laravel

Tags: javascript, php, facebook, laravel, facebook-sdk-4.0

I use js-sdk with php-sdk and this is my php code when js is login

loginController.php

```
FacebookSession::setDefaultApplication('appid','sec');
$helper = new FacebookJavaScriptLoginHelper();
try {
    $session = $helper->getSession();
} catch(FacebookRequestException $ex) {
    // When Facebook returns an error
} catch(\Exception $ex) {
    // When validation fails or other local issues
}
if ($session) {
    // Work!
}
```

it work at first and ***Not work*** when php session is expire

js is work fine.
this is my js
.js on index page

```
function Login() {
FB.login(function(response) {
    if (response.status === 'connected') {
        FB.api('/me', function(data) {
            if(data.email == null) {
                // Fail
            } else {
                // OK redirect to .php
                window.location.href = "{{ action('UserController@getLogin') }}"
            }
        });
    } else {
        // Fail
    }
}, {scope: 'public_profile,email'});
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK I got that
I for got

```
cookie : true,
```

on

```
FB.init
```

= = my 3 hours back pls.